# lambda and filter in a list

Tags: python, filter, lambda

I am trying to understand this code, it gives me a list of all the words that start with s.
What I don't understand is how simply using `x [0] == 's'`, it only evaluates the first letter of the word in the list and not the whole word, that is, **x [0]** would correspond to **soup** not only the first letter.
Thanks

```
seq = ['soup','dog','salad','cat','great']
result = list(filter(lambda x: (x[0] == 's'), seq)) 
print(result)
```

Comment: `x[0]` returns the first letter of each string, == is the operator for equality

Comment: And `filter` invokes the function (in this case your `lambda`) on each *individual* element of the list in turn, not the entire list -- so `x` is bound to a different specific word each time the lambda is called.

Comment: To make it easier to understand, change the lambda to a regular function and step through it or print the values of `x` that the function receives.

Comment: maybe put code in normal function `def` instead of `lambda` and then you may use `print()` inside `def` to see what you have in variable(s)